# Problem in datagridview in .net winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I have return cellvaluechanged event for my column1 which contains the category combo box.if i select the category i need to display the selectedvalue to column 4 .how can i do that?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hai ayps,

Try this one hope it helps http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxeditingcontrol.aspx

and

http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/28298-Getting-Selected-Value-Combo-Box.aspx

**EDIT:**
[Windows DataGridView _RowCommand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1877240/windows-datagridview-rowcommand)